# Beginner finger lessons for virtual piano

Tags: piano, fingering, virtual-instrument

I found the site VIRTUALPIANO NET and would like to learn how to play the virtual piano(VP) using it since I cant afford an actual piano. I decided to start with finger training in the C major scale but the keyboard positions on the VP are just laid out sequentially without regard to the finger position starting at C. I doubt thats possible using a computer keyboard either. I was wondering if anyone knows any free online lessons that train you to use your fingers correctly for a VP?

Btw, the layout on VirtualPiano is a 36 key layout  using only Shift, number and letter keys. Shift and another key is used to access the black keys. The C on the keyboard from low to high are marked by 1,8,t,s,l,m

Comment: There really is no substitute for a piano keyboard, if you want to learn piano technique. If you can't afford a real piano, at least get a cheap synth.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding off-site resources including lessons is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard layout used on that VP is appalling.  Compared to http://www.onlinepianist.com/virtual_piano/ or http://www.multiplayerpiano.com or http://method-behind-the-music.com/piano, for example.  The layout there is far more logical.  It's the type of layout used by a lot of music authoring software too (good authoring software would have configurable keyboard layouts anyway, but their default configuration is actually usually very easy to use).

In these tools, (Assuming a QWERTY keyboard) Q and Z are expected to play C and the the rest of those rows to play the white notes.  The black notes are therefore where one would expect (e.g. 2,3,5,6,7,9,0).

I don't think there's any point struggling with that VP you found, it will be effort for nothing.

Oh, as others have already said, a VP can be fun, and you can certainly tap out a simple melody, but they don't teach you the finger skills for real piano.

Comment: I agree the finger layout is horrible when trying to include the black keys but the site has links to many videos showing users playing complex songs using only white keys

Comment: @user1278255 Leaving aside the perfectly valid questions others have asked about why you're fixated on using a virtual piano at all, why are you so stuck on using this one particular, poor implementation of a virtual piano?  As Lee points out (with links!) there are any number of better layout VPs, which have the added advantage of being more like those used in more sophisticated programs. Playing a VP will teach very little of use for an actual keyboard instrument, but ones with a better layout will at least come a little bit closer.

Comment: just because i have a current interest in music and i dont want to shell out on a real keyboard until i know i have some skill in making some music

Comment: @user1278255 The skills using a VP with a more logical keyboard layout will be more transferable.

Comment: @user1278255 I wasn't asking why you are using a virtual piano in general, I'm asking why you're fixated on this particular one. As Lee says, there are other VPs that are *far* better, check those links, they're free too. I think your plan to discover whether you have musical talent via virtual piano is a little crazy, but you might as well do the best version of it that you can, right?

Comment: Very well, I found one called VPMK which lets you map the keys yourself and I'll try that out. But Virtual Piano is still an excellent choice because of the range it offers with its mapping. Simply take a look onsite showing the songs its users have made. The problem, I think, is that you are all musical purists here and cant stand that idea of someone deviating from the norm of a real piano. If I do buy a real piano, I can learn thr way to play with it. If I'm using an online one, the layout doesn't have to be realistic, just simple to learn.

Comment: @user1278255: There are better ways to achieve range, other VPs use shift to transpose octave, as a keyboard player, that is a lot more playable. I saw the YouTube channel, it's amazing how some have conquered the interface, but difficult to say whether these players are more skilled as musicians or gamers to be frank (from a musical perspective, they're not mp3-worthy, that's my benchmark for judging music). I'm not a musical purist, I have no intention of buying a real piano, ever. Only trying to help. It sounds like you might have been drawn to the social media aspect of that particular VP.

Answer (score 4):

**If you're sure you want to use virtual piano** there are some example songs that you can pull up within the software. If you already know the tune you don't have to worry about rhythm and it will help your muscle memory to remember certain patterns of notes.

**A better idea is probably to purchase a really cheap piano keyboard.** A quick amazon search for me revealed [a keyboard for 50 dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VX1GI8), and you can probably find better deals on eBay. Playing on real-sized keys will do you much better in learning how to play the piano. Honestly, virtual piano is more of a game than a tool, and the most I use it for is transcribing melodies when I have no other instrument around me.

Comment: Sorry I was looking for basic finger training exercises. The Facebook page for VP does list the keyboard keys for some songs but I dont think I'm advanced enough for that and anyway learning by keys wont teach me the notes for the song.

Comment: @user I really don't see the point in finger training exercises using a computer keyboard instead of a piano keyboard. Playing the piano is nothing like typing, and so any skill you develop on the computer keyboard is unlikely to ever translate to a real instrument. The virtual piano seems like it's only useful for learning theory, not performance skills. Take this answer's advice and get a real keyboard controller, if even a dirt cheap one!

Answer (score 0):

A more recent alternative to virtual piano with a different key mapping can be found here: [Recursive Arts Virtual Piano](http://recursivearts.com/virtual-piano/).

Further details about [key mappings](http://recursivearts.com/virtual-piano/keymapping.html) are also available.

Comment: Welcome to Music Stack Exchange.  The site welcomes cogent on-target answers and questions.  Especially when it revives an old question as you have done here.  Again, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way youd be able to play VP the same way you would using a real piano, since youd be using a computer keyboard instead but at the same time it isnt also that hard to play vp (if u get what Im saying- ;-;.) To play vp, your hands need to be quick, and be able to memorize which "key" to press sometimes by memory. I suggest you try vp sheets that mostly have single notes or that look like "dsagfuisahgj". Once your able to do sheets with single notes somewhat good, you can try doubles. "s f [el] [uk] [pl]" and so on. It takes practice and a lot of time tho. The most important thing about VP would be knowing where each key is and being able to press them, as said, sometimes without looking- Im not good at explaining so basically like, pressing keys by memory, almost the same as being able to type fast on the keyboard. For sheets that would include Shift like "[rW] [Wi] [Wr]" u  would just need to practice doing it, its gonna be hard, but if you really wanna improve then yeah- (;-;.). what im suggesting here wont be able to help you play good on an actual piano, but it could help in playing a virtual one. Idk if this was helpful or not aaaaaaa.

Answer (score -2):

I may have worked out a solution to this question by myself:

This only worked for white keys since using Shift to play black keys is not very viable.
When I say use hand here it always excludes thumb. When I use '&' in the following list it does not refer to the keyboard key.
- Use left hand for keys 1-4&5 using index finger for both 4&5
- Use right hand for keys 6&7-0 using index finger for both 6&7
- Use left hand for keys qwer&t using index finger for both r&t
- Use right hand for keys y&uiop using index finger for both y&u
- Use left hand for keys asdf&g using index finger for both f&g
- Use right hand for keys g&hjkl using index finger for both g&h
- Use left hand for keys zxcv (4 fingers on this hand to improve pinkie finger strength)
- Use right hand for keys bnm

Train your finger using the following methods. Only move to the next method after mastering the previous one:
-Move the hands up and down the different rows playing the keys in order
-Move the hands up and down the different rows, think of a note and press the finger that 
 matches the note
-Play basic melodies using different octaves

Comment: You may have been learning how to play a "VP," but none of these skills will transfer to anything that has black and white keys.